# Why is add at specific index slower in LinkedLists than in ArrayLists

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, linked-list

I was checking this chart containing performances comparisons among lists:

[image]

And I find it very odd that adding and removing elements at a specific index performs faster in an `ArrayList` than it does in a `LinkedList`. Is this chart wrong? The whole idea of a `LinkedList` is to improve such operations, while paying with reduced iteration performance. But this chart seems to indicate that Java's implementation of `LinkedLists` is very poorly done.

Should I trust the chart? And if so, why Java `LinkedLists` perform so bad?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The whole idea of a LinkedList is to improve such operations, while paying with reduced iteration performance.

No, the idea of a linked list is to make adding or removing *at the end or beginning* very cheap... or if you have a reference to a node object already, adding around that or removing it is very cheap too. (I don't think the Java API exposes the nodes, but some other platforms like .NET do.)

To add at an *index* within a linked list, the implementation first has to navigate to the node at that index... which is an O(n) operation. Once it's got there, the add is cheap. So adding by index near the start (or end with a smart implementation) is cheap, but adding by index near the middle is expensive.

With an `ArrayList`, the expense comes from:

- Copying the existing elements beyond the index you're adding
- Copying the whole thing is the buffer isn't big enough

Comment: Java doesn't expose the node, but the LinkedList's iterator allows adding an element at a given position. So adding an element every 3 positions for example is less complex in a linked list than in an arraylist, which would have to constantly shift all the remaining elements to the right).

Comment: Sorry @Jon, I have no idea what "that's a silver lining" means :-(

Comment: @JBNizet: It means that it doesn't make up for the lack of access to the node directly, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Educational and succint reply, enriched by @JBNizet 's observation. The cost of navigating the list ends up being higher than the cost of copying the whole list over for adding or removing at arbitrary index, but if your logic allows the operations to be done via an iterator then LinkedLists perform better, and the chart doesn't cover that case.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed. I had to find a rather convoluted use-case to illustrate when that can be useful.

Comment: @JBNizet [here is an account of the phrase's origin](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/every-cloud-has-a-silver-lining.html). Uncultured swine as I am, I didn't realise it came from John Milton.

Comment: Part of the reason iterating a linked list is so expensive is that it will often trigger numerous cache misses, since linked lists have poorer memory locality than vectors.  Copying a big, contiguous chunk of memory (with a vector) is often cheaper than navigating a bunch of non-contiguous chunks of memory.

Answer (score 2):

A general information:

Making micro benchmark is influenced by many factors, so it is not so easy to define a micro benchmark that is reliable for little numbers.

---

The insertion can be seen as a two step process:

- Find position
- Insert element

The first step, find position, is done in O(n), the second step in O(1) for a `LinkedList`.

Using an `ArrayList` finding the position is O(1), instead the insertion is done in O(n). Moving records one position (to create space for a new element) is done using native libraries so it is a quite fast operation.